# How can boost::asio::buffer_cast violate type-safety?

Tags: c++

Comments are sprinkled throughout [boost::asio](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/9bfe806fc1d2a51c97b433571f42b83606a28b05/include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp#L89) that say this:

> The boost::asio::buffer_cast function permits violations of type
>   safety, so uses of it in application code should be carefully
>   considered.

However, ultimately what the buffer interface boils down to is this:

```
struct buffer {
  void *data;

  friend void* cast_helper(const buffer& b);
};

void* cast_helper(const buffer& b) {
  return b.data;
}

template <typename to_t>
to_t buffer_cast(const buffer& b) {
  return static_cast<to_t>(cast_helper(b));
}
```

`static_cast` a `void*` to a pointer type is well-defined and considered the appropriate thing to do for `void*` data (see "Should I use static_cast or reinterpret_cast when casting a void* to whatever"). So what does it mean by violating type-safety?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code:

```
    char i = 2;
    buffer b;
    b.data = &i;
    double *pd = buffer_cast<double*>(b);

    *pd = 1.0;
```

This will compile correctly, but it obviously invokes undefined behaviour.  It's no different really to:

```
    char i = 2;
    void *pv = &i;
    double *pd = static_cast<double*>(pv);
    *pd = 1.0;
```

In both the case of `static_cast` and `buffer_cast` a reviewer needs to look carefully at the code to make sure the cast is legal.

Using `static_cast` to convert a `void*` to a pointer type is only well defined if the void* was originally obtained from a pointer of that type or something similar (where "similar" includes some, but not all, base/derived relationships, and unsigned char vs plain char vs signed char, etc).